# How to get request path variable value from Node server to AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, ejs

I would like the value of the `token` path variable from inside an email client (Gmail for example) through a link sent to the Node server using ExpressJS and then have the value available in a controller (`MyController`).

The server is displaying the view `reset.ejs` and passing the passing the `token` value to it as a parameter.

Following is the code for the above case:

**server.js (ExpressJS)**

```
app.get('/reset/:token', function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
            res.render('reset', {  title: 'Foo  in a Bar', token: req.params.token, invalidTokenMsg: "Password reset token is invalid or has expired" });
        } else {
            res.render('reset', {  title: 'Foo in a Bar', token: req.params.token, invalidTokenMsg: "Choose a strong password" });
        }
    });
});
```

**reset.ejs (EJS)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="myApp">
<!-- stuff inside head -->
<head>

</head>
<body >
    <!-- stuff inside body-->
</html>
```

**myapp.js (AngularJS)**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    //how to get the value of token here?
}]);
```

How somebody tell me how could I get the `token` value in a controller?

Answer (score 2):

ideally, the request call must be originating from inside the controller. won't it be like,

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', $http, function($scope) {
    $http.get('reset/:token',{token:'xyzabc'}).then(function(data){
     });
}]);
```

(or) if the token is more like a global object, you can use $provide.constant and inject into other controller objects.